# LoadLibrary failed when running Loadrunner 12.53

Tags: multithreading, dll, fatal-error, loadrunner, loadlibrary

> Fatal Error -32988: LoadLibrary failed, rc=193   [MsgId: MERR-32988]
>
> Fatal Error -26000: xfbLrwiWebInfraGlobalInitOK failed   [MsgId: MERR-26000]
>
> Warning: Extension lrwreplaymain.dll reports error -1 on call to function ExtPerProcessInitialize
> Error: Thread Context: Call to service of the driver failed, reason - thread context wasn't initialized on this thread.

Recording is passed but cannot replayed due to the above error.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `lrwreplaymain.dll` or some of the DLLs it depends on were corrupted (error code 193 = ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT). This may have been caused by virus attack, file system corruption etc.

The easiest solution is to re-install LoadRunner. You can also check which DLLs are corrupted by means of [the Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) x86. Just start it and open `<LoadRunner installation folder>\bin\lrwreplaymain.dll`

Comment: Thanks for helping. The Walker shows that "API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L 1-1-0.DLL" and "....WINRT-STRING-L 1-..." are missing. Google said it may due to missing "Visual C++ Redistributable Package". But I have installed required 2010, 12, 13 and 15 versions already... Please help!

Comment: @WingYanYeung, try reinstalling these redistributables, they may have been corrupted.

Comment: Resolved the problem after reinstalled the OS. Many thanks!